# Shifting display groups around in a lua table

Tags: lua, coronasdk, lua-table

I am working on a camera module for my game.  I am specifically designing it to work with very large amounts of randomly generated data.  The data are in the form of 2d chunks.  They are labeled and referenced by actual x, y coordinates.  Each chunk has a group attached to it in order to contain the images associated with it.  I have a group that contains only the chunks that are on screen ( my simple simple attempt at culling ).  When the player moves in any direction by the width of a chunk, all the current chunks need to shift in the table by one element and a new row ( or column ) of chunks needs to be loaded in the edge row ( or column ).  My problem comes when I do the shifting.  I am getting an error that says that I have either already removed that image group or its parent group.  The problem is that I haven't done this.  The following code is the section I am having issues in ( I think the whole code is to large to post all at once ):

Note:  At the VERY end is the section where the removal of elements occurs.  I have it marked with asterisks.

```
if( changeBottom == true ) then
 for i = 1, newView.numViewChunksY - 1 do
  for j = 1, newView.numViewChunksX do
   newView.imageChunkTable[i][j] = newView.imageChunkTable[i + 1][j]
  end
 end
 for j = 1, newView.numViewChunksX do
 local i = newView.numViewChunksY
 local metaX
 local metaY
 if( newView.metaLoadingData.L == true ) then
  if( ( newView.curChunk.x + ( j - 3 )*chunkSize ) < newView.curMetaChunk.x ) then
   metaX = 1
  else
   metaX = 2
  end
 elseif( newView.metaLoadingData.R == true ) then
  if( ( newView.curChunk.x + ( j - 3 )*chunkSize ) > ( newView.curMetaChunk.x + metaChunkSize*chunkSize ) ) then
   metaX = 2
  else
   metaX = 1
  end
 else
  metaX = 1
 end
 if( newView.metaLoadingData.T == true ) then
  if( ( ( newView.curChunk.y + ( i - 2 )*chunkSize ) < newView.curMetaChunk.y ) ) then
   metaY = 1
  else
   metaY = 2
  end
 elseif( newView.metaLoadingData.B == true ) then
  if( ( newView.curChunk.y + ( i - 2 )*chunkSize ) >= newView.curMetaChunk.y + metaChunkSize*chunkSize ) then
   metaY = 2
  else
   metaY = 1
  end
 else
  metaY = 1
 end
 local chunk = newView.metaChunkTable[metaY][metaX].chunkTable[ ( newView.curChunk.y + ( i - 2 )*chunkSize )/chunkSize - newView.metaChunkTable[metaY][metaX].y/chunkSize + 1 ][ ( newView.curChunk.x + ( j - 3 )*chunkSize )/chunkSize - newView.metaChunkTable[metaY][metaX].x/chunkSize + 1 ]
 newView.imageChunkTable[newView.numViewChunksY][j].displayGroup:removeSelf()----------
 newView.imageChunkTable[newView.numViewChunksY][j] = nil                       *
 newView.imageChunkTable[newView.numViewChunksY][j] = imageChunk.new( chunk )   *
end
```

**EDIT :**  The exact wording of the error I am getting ( without file paths ) is as follows:

ERROR: Attempt to remove an object that's already been removed from the stage or whose parent/ancestor group has already been removed.

Here is the line that is referenced by the debugger:

```
newView.imageChunkTable[newView.numViewChunksY][j].displayGroup:removeSelf()
```

I have marked it in the code with hyphens.

**EDIT 2 :**  imageChunk module:

```
local imageChunk = {}
local imageChunk_mt = { __index = imageChunk }

function imageChunk.new( infoChunk )
 local chunkSize = 10
 local tileSize = 48

 local newImageChunk = {
  objTable = {},
  displayGroup = display.newGroup()
        }
 for i = 1, infoChunk.numLayers do
  newImageChunk.objTable[i] = {}
  for j = 1, infoChunk.layer[i].numMembers do
   newImageChunk.objTable[i][j] = display.newImage( infoChunk.layer[i].group[j].kind.."/"..infoChunk.layer[i].group[j].subKind..".png", infoChunk.layer[i].group[j].x, infoChunk.layer[i].group[j].y )
   newImageChunk.displayGroup:insert( newImageChunk.objTable[i][j] )
  end
 end

 return setmetatable( newImageChunk, imageChunk_mt )
end

return imageChunk
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the `newView.numViewChunksY][j].displayGroup` is the same for two or more `j`. Also depending on when the error occurs (if first shift ok but second shift fails, for example), it could be that the `newView.numViewChunksY][j] = imageChunk.new( chunk )` is incorrect: maybe `imageChunk.new()` returns nil or doesn't return a group. 
Update:

Based on your update, I'm wondering where the code is that shows call to `imageChunk.new` other than the last line. Also it is not true that each j corresponds to different image chunk display group: `newView.imageChunkTable[i][j] = newView.imageChunkTable[i + 1][j]`, that could be cause of problem.

Comment: I had thought about that, but since j is iterated through a for loop, there is no instance where it is repeated.  The function imageChunk.new() is correct; I have posted the imageChunk module for you to see.  Let me know if I need to post more code for you to know exactly what's going on.